# Update permissions to a file not deployed by puppet

Tags: file, puppet

I would like to know how to update the permissions for a file that is not getting deployed by puppet. The file is actually getting deployed by an RPM. I have tried the following with no luck:

```
file { '/some/directory/myfile.conf' :
  ensure  => 'file',
  replace => 'no',
  owner   => 'someuser',
  group   => 'somegroup',
  mode    => '0644'
}
```

This actually removes the content of the file and leaves an empty file. However it  sets the right permissions and mode. I would like to keep the content. I am using puppet 2.7.3.

Comment: Although that is an extremely obsolete version of puppet, try removing the `ensure` parameter and see if it does not try to control the state after that change.

Comment: Although `'no'` is documented as a valid value for the `replace` parameter, I suggest using the more conventional `false` instead.  In any event, Puppet should not be changing the content of an existing file if you do not declare a `content` or `source` on the file.  Overall, I have to wonder whether something else is responsible for the change you observe, instead.

Comment: I was able to update puppet to 3.7.3 and it actually worked. Not sure if something was wrong with 2.7.3.